# I cannot find my project dll in visual studio code

Tags: g1ant

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFfk0.png)

Can anyone help me find the problem here even after I am uninstalling and reinstalling G1ANT  and its extension I am getting this error.Please give me a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

First you build then debug if required..